# pom для spring-boot и wildfly

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, jboss, wildfly

Есть Spring-Boot проект, собранный maven-ом, который также деплоится на wildfly. Для этого вношу ряд изменений в pom, указываю, что упакововать нужно в war, исключаю конфликтные артефакты. У меня сейчас два пома, для каждой сборки, можно ли сделать все в одном поме и указывать параметры профилей или что-то подобное?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да, можно.

Ваша задача как раз таки и решается через профили.

Добавляете в `pom.xml` `<profiles>`-тэг, в нем определяете информацию о профиле, ну а дальше - по сути, внутри профиля xml-структура будет аналогична той, что у вас есть в обычном pom-файле.

Вот вам небольшой пример структуры:

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>dev</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
        <properties>
            <logback.loglevel>DEBUG</logback.loglevel>
        </properties>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jetty</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
                <optional>true</optional>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>prod</id>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jetty</artifactId>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.5</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <filesets>
                            <fileset>
                                <directory>src/main/webapp/dist</directory>
                            </fileset>
                            <fileset>
                                <directory>.tmp</directory>
                            </fileset>
                            <fileset>
                                <directory>node_modules</directory>
                            </fileset>
                        </filesets>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <configuration>
                        <executable>false</executable>
                        <arguments>
                            <argument>--spring.profiles.active=prod</argument>
                        </arguments>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
        <properties>
            <logback.loglevel>INFO</logback.loglevel>
        </properties>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

Думаю, здесь все очевидно...

Если пользуетесь IDEA, то там переключение профилей регулируется одной проставляемой галкой в maven-projects, что очень удобно.